# Bash linux force multiple instances to wait for running sqlplus command to finish

Tags: linux, bash, shell, connection, sqlplus

I have a bash script that allows multiple running instances at once. There is, however, a sqlplus connection to an Oracle database to retrieve a value. If this value is being fetched by multiple bash script instances at once, they might retrieve the same value, because while the first instance is still processing, the second instance is already validating the 'old data'.

I can only think of two option, which is locking the function by a PIDFILE. Downside is that if the user aborts the operation before the pidfile gets removed, it will cause problems. Another is locking the whole script based on declaring maximum processes counted with `ps -ef | grep 'scriptname' | wc -l`. But this would lock the whole script, and not just the database part.

So is there maybe another option? Is this sqlplus connection to the database somehow possible to catch so I can place the multiple running instances on pause while this function is being executed by one of the instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a unique value in a tmp file (`/tmp/pidfile` for this example), and have it reset upon abort or completion of script.

**Update:** This seems solid, see tests down bottom.

```
#!/bin/bash


bashpid="$$"                     # Records PID of script.  Unused so far
pidfile=/tmp/pidfile             # pidfile var
pidlimit=2                       # pidlimit

cleanup () {                     # cleanup operations
        exit
    }

pidreset () {                    # trap operations (if reqd)
        pkill -a -P "$bashpid"
        kill -9 0
    }

trap "pidreset" SIGINT           # trap (if reqd)


countpid () {                    # This is the true PID count, only called
                                 # Once allowed in the database block
                                 # This includes self instance

     ps aux | grep "$(basename $0)" | grep -v grep > $pidfile

}

countloop () {                   # This counts PID while waiting for a spot
                                 # (-1 decrement since self is included but 
                                 # not yet granted access to database block)
    echo "(( ("$(ps aux | grep "$(basename $0)" | grep -v grep | wc -l )") - 1))" | bc > $pidfile

}
databasecall () {                # The database script calls

    touch $pidfile
    pidcount="$(cat $pidfile | wc -l)"
    until [[ "$pidcount" -le "$pidlimit" ]]; do
        echo "too many processes"
        countloop 
        pidcount="$(cat $pidfile | wc -l)"
        sleep 5
    done

    #   ================  Start of Database access Code ================
    #   Go ahead and do database stuff
    #   Write this script into the pidfile incrementing its count also

    countpid 
    pidcount="$(cat $pidfile | wc -l)"
    echo "We're in"
    echo "Scriptcount: $pidcount (Including this one)"
    sleep 5
    cleanup
    # return / whatever
    #   ================  End of Database access Code ================

}



echo "Main script block"          # Main script outside of Database block
sleep .1


databasecall                      # Call database function


cleanup                           # Call to housekeeping
```

**Tests**

It works fine but settles at running one more than pidlimit, though i'm not certain where this is occurring or if it's my test scenario yet.

```
bash>echo "imrunning & sleep .5 ; imrunning & sleep .5 ; imrunning & sleep .5 ; imrunning & sleep .5 ; imrunning" > /tmp/initrunning ; chmod +x /tmp/initrunning
bash>/tmp/./initrunning 
Main script block
We're in
Scriptcount:        1 (Including this one)
Main script block
We're in
Scriptcount:        2 (Including this one)
Main script block
too many processes
Main script block
too many processes
Main script block
too many processes
We're in
Scriptcount:        3 (Including this one)
We're in
Scriptcount:        3 (Including this one)
We're in
Scriptcount:        3 (Including this one)
bash
```

Comment: Well this sure does not make my script any simpler haha. Pretty much cumbersome compared to locking the whole script, but I guess it works.

I will need some time to test all this and to adapt my script. So there is only one other option that I learnt after this (but which I also didn't try yet); is to create a schema user which only allows 1 connection.

Anyhow, thank you for your code, time and effort! :)

Comment: @IvanM I hear you!  I've focused more on the ability to lock one part of the script as it wasn't clear to me initially that you were trying to lock strictly one connection to the database.   There's a lot of unknowns at my end, but a couple thoughts .., does the SESSIONS_PER_USER parameter affect read operations ?  If you're trying to completely restrict reading; depending on performance needs - you could use `lsof -t /path/to/db.sql` to detect physical access to the file.

Comment: @IvanM As for the aborting operation .. to mitigate the "user abort" situation, you could remove/check/cleanup the lockfile in the cleanup() section above.  It's templates to catch a ctrl+c, but you could assign whatever event would be appropriate as originating from the end user.

Comment: `lsof` you say...That's new to me. And yes. to give a little more detail, my script creates a .sql file then applies this in a `sqlplus`-run command. So with `lsof` I can detect that this file is being accessed and that way make the second running instance placed in queue until this file is not accessed anymore?

Comment: It can, you'll need to test.  `lsof` operates on open file descriptors of various types via the kernel (see `man lsof`). DB's can use various and combinations of approaches to apply shared or exclusive locks on files.  Remember that database locking systems are designed around protecting the integrity of data within.  It's not as common to limit read only instances, as this is typically done using an authentication system, or in todays cloud services using an API.  So for a small application where physical read access must be only 1 at a time, I'd suggest `lsof` may work well.

Comment: @IvanM, also, you may wish to use multiple approaches yourself, depending on the importance of avoiding the multiple access situation.  The only issue you might have with `lsof` is that while it may run *before* accessing the database, there may be (very far fetched...but again, depends on the consequence of such a thing happening) a situation where another instance also enquired, just a few milliseconds later, and if two get the all clear at nearly the same time, they will both have the all clear to go ahead....

Comment: @IvanM.  A way you could prevent this form of race condition would be to also have your own locking system.  

This command for instance will *always* return TWO "file exists":  `mkdir /tmp/hello & mkdir /tmp/hello & mkdir /tmp/hello`.  By employing an inline "create if non-existent / skip if exists" condition right before the sql, you'll have mitigated that risk properly.  The housekeeping could be removing the lockfile as part of the cleanup() function, on exit, and say using a special maintenance argument (where it could call `lsof` and `ps aux | grep sqlplus | grep -v grep` for example)